# How can you drag and drop a list item to a label so it's the label's text in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop, label

I want to be able to drag list items from a list box onto labels so that when you drop the list item, that becomes the text for the label.

I think I've got the mouse down part correct:

```
private void listPlayers_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DoDragDrop(listPlayers.SelectedItem.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
```

I also believe this is correct for the `dragEnter` event for the `label`:

```
private void posLB_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            else
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
```

However, I have no idea how to get the `DragDrop` event working for the `label`. I thought it would be something like this:

```
private void posLB_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            posLB.text(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        }
```

But that has errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for correct type and then grab it:

```
    private void posLB_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            String s = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as String;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                posLB.Text = s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It complains about posLB.Text(s); with the following: "Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text' cannot be used like a method.